# Cannot resolve name:weblogic.jms.ConnectionFactory

Tags: java, connection, jms, weblogic, jms-topic

I'm writing an application to browse messages on a JMS Topic. Below is my code for getting an initial context and initializing the topic:

```
public final static String JNDI_FACTORY="oracle.jms.AQjmsInitialContextFactory";
public final static String JMS_FACTORY="weblogic.jms.ConnectionFactory";

private void initTopic(Context context, String topicName) throws NamingException, JMSException {
    System.out.println("initializing the queue...");
    topicFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
    topicConnection = topicFactory.createTopicConnection();

    //queueConnection.setExceptionListener(this);
    topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    System.out.println("session created, lookup queue: " + topicName);

    topic = (Topic)context.lookup(topicName);
    System.out.println("done...");
}


private InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException
{
    System.out.println("Opening connection to " + SERVER);
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
    //env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, SERVER);
    env.put(AQjmsContext.DB_URL, SERVER);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, WLUSER);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, WLPASSWORD);
    return new InitialContext(env);
}
```

When I try to run I'm getting the error:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot resolve name:weblogic.jms.ConnectionFactory [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unrecognized prefix in: weblogic.jms.ConnectionFactory]
```

edit: Pretty sure all I had to do was set `JMS_FACTORY="ConnectionFactory"`

Comment: Did you create the JMS factory?

Comment: @Rouliboy The change I described in my edit got rid of the original NamingException but then I got a new error `java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jms.AQjmsConnectionFactory cannot be cast to javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory`. To get rid of this error, I changed how I was setting the topicFactory and topicConnection variables to `topicFactory = (AQjmsConnectionFactory) context.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);` and `topicConnection = (TopicConnection) topicFactory.createConnection();`. Now I'm getting `oracle.jms.AQjmsException: No suitable driver found for (name of the server I'm connecting to)`.